# How to change markers for particular points in a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I plot something like:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 10 * x;
plot(x, y)
```

what should I do if I want particular points on the graph to have a particular marker (while all other points remain neutral)?

For instance, I have a logical matrix as shown below:

```
I = logical([0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]);
```

I want all `true` values in `I` to have a special marker (say, a star). I intend to plot multiple graphs on the same plot so I'd preferably want markers on top of the original graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you'll have to use a different `plot` command for the special markers (this might affect the behavior of `legend`, but I'm not sure).

```
plot( x, y ); % regular plot
hold on; % make sure old plot sticks around
plot( x(I), y(I), 'h' ); % only markers as stars
```

For example (`y=rand(1,10)`):
[image]

Comment: `I` is logical, so `x(I)` and `y(I)` should suffice.

Comment: @EitanT you are correct. But as `I` is posted in the question it is not 100% clear it is indeed a logical array. So, I decided to be on the safe side on this one.

Comment: it says explicitly that `I` is logical.

Comment: @EitanT indeed. But `I=[0 0 0 1 0 1]` when you copy-paste to matlab creates a `double` array and not a logical one... annoying feature.

Comment: @EitanT ok. Happy chanukkah.